# Return 10 without exit -PHP

Tags: php, return

`$ifvalid` if true should return 1. 
In below case whenvalue was true it returns 10 
if I put exit it properly returns 1. 
**Why so ?**

Ajax call

**JS -Calling AJAX**

```
var data = {
   action: "validate_date",
   start_date: 22/2/2017,
   end_date: 22/7/2017,
}; 

$.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
   alert(response)
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    function validate_date(){
       $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
       $expiration_date= $_POST['end_date'];
       $ifValid = check_in_range($start_date, $expiration_date);

       echo  $ifValid; //returns 10
       echo  $ifValid;exit;  //returns 1
    }

    function check_in_range($start_date, $end_date)
    {
       // Convert to timestamp
       $start_ts = strtotime($start_date);
       $end_ts = strtotime($end_date);
       $timeNow = strtotime("now");
       // Check that user date is between start & end
       return (($timeNow >= $start_ts) && ($timeNow <= $end_ts));
    }
?>
```

in Response of this ajax i do `alert(response);`

Comment: share function `check_in_range` ?

Comment: @Niklesh done..

Comment: What's the reason for downvote ?

Comment: Check this : https://eval.in/747873

Comment: @Niklesh Ok .. I am getting 10. Everything is in AJAX call . May be because of that ?

Comment: share ajax code too and exact code to understand I am confused on `}`  here `echo  $ifValid;exit;  //returns 1
    }`

Answer (score 0):

> You can set function like below

```
function check_in_range($start_date, $end_date)
{
  // Convert to timestamp
  $start_ts = strtotime($start_date);
  $end_ts = strtotime($end_date);
  $timeNow = strtotime("now");

  // Check that user date is between start & end
  if(($timeNow >= $start_ts) && ($timeNow <= $end_ts)){
      return '1'; // OR return '0'; as you want
  }else{
      return '0'; // OR return '1'; as you want
  }
}
```